# How to set line-height to font-size plus fixed value for entire project

Tags: html, css, sass, font-size

I have to adjust line heights for an entire existing project. The specification is that all line heights should be the font-size + 4px.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this using scss?

Adjusting based on percentage would be straight-forward, but the fixed value is throwing me off.

Also would I be able to set this globally without having to set this for each class where font-size is altered.

Comment: you can set it on your body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many way to do that:

1. `$fontSize` is a static value defined in `px`:

```css
$fontSize: 12px;

$lineHeight: $fontSize + 4;
```

2. your `font-size` value is dynamic and must be computed at runtime:

```css
line-height: calc(1em + 4x);
```

---

example using [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc);

```css
p {
  font-size: 14px; background: yellow;
}

.lh {
  line-height: calc(1em + 4px);
}
```

```html
<p class="lh">Hello World</p>
```